# How to get a Check Button Value

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a check button in my program. when I click the check button, the var value is always 0. Shouldn't the value be 1 when clicked. It works in a small program that i made but when I try to get a check button value in my big program, the value is always 0 no matter how many times I click the checkbutton. The following code is the small example program that I wrote which works just fine but when I try to get the var value in my bigger program, the value is always 0.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")


def check():
    global var2
    var2 = IntVar()
    c=Checkbutton(root, text="click me", variable=var2, command=show)
    c.pack()

    myButton=Button(root, text="show selection", command=show).pack()

def show():
    myLabel = Label(root, text=var2.get()).pack()

check()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I forgot to say that my question is related to Python Tkinter

Comment: Then [edit] your post and add a tag for both Python and Tkinter, instead of putting it in a comment. The [edit] link (besides being clickable in my comment) is beneath the tags.

Comment: Please [edit]  your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: Can you post the larger code? This would mean we get to run your program. Also, it seems as if you have a global issue when you put this small snippet in your larger code.

Comment: I can post my larger code but it is a pretty big program.

Comment: Can I email my code to you? Or is that allowed?

Comment: Big problem?Have you used many `Tk()` instances at the same time?

Comment: you can set `onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0` in the parameters of `CheckButton` to verify if the `Checkbutton` is working

Comment: Yes, I did that and still not working.

Comment: also in `show()`, you need to say `global var2` before you can access it inside

Comment: That didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I figured it out. Well, thanks to Google. When opening up a new window instead of calling Tk() I changed it to Toplevel() and it finally worked. Thanks for all of your input.

Comment: Your question doesn't show that you're using multiple windows.

Answer (score -1):

You needed to use `BooleanVar()`. Hope it helps.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")


def check():
    global var2
    var2 = BooleanVar()
    c=Checkbutton(root, text="click me", variable=var2, command=show)
    c.pack()

    myButton=Button(root, text="show selection", command=show).pack()

def show():
    myLabel = Label(root, text=int(var2.get())).pack()
    # commented out the lower label, it returned False instead of one.
    # It's always a good idea to force variables to be what they should be.
    # myLabel = Label(root, text=var2.get()).pack()

check()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: That didn't work. No matter how many times I clicked the check box, it just printed 'False'

Comment: That's strange, with me it's ones and zero's. Maybe a python configuration or version difference... Or something in the rest of your program. But anyway, you can use this to change it to ones and zeros: ```myLabel = Label(root, text=int(var2.get())).pack()```. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Keep in mind. The code I listed works. But in my larger program where I have a check button, the var value only returns 0 no matter if it is checked or not.

Comment: Then the problem lies somewhere else in your code. Is it possible that you already used a global var2? For me ```IntVar()``` returned zero as well. No matter what I did.

Comment: Could I send you my code to look at and run and test.

Comment: Sure thing, but we should move this to chat then. I see you dont have enough points for that. I'm figuring out how I can contact you on stackoverflow. I'm new here as well.

Comment: Okay, my username with @protonmail.com should work. I'm surprised it's so difficult to PM here.

Comment: Well, I figured it out. Well, thanks to Google.  When opening up a new window instead of calling Tk() I changed to Toplevel() and it finally worked. Thanks for all of your input.